# How to implement a search bar that dismisses itself when user taps outside it

Tags: ipad, uigesturerecognizer, uisearchbar

I'm building an iPad app. I'm trying to implement a UISearchBar as a view that dismisses itself if the user taps outside of it.

When the Search button is tapped, I create a search bar and animate it into position above my table view. I also create a UITapGestureRecognizer subclass (I'll explain this in a moment) and add it to the app's window:

```
- (void) searchTap:(id)sender
{
    if (!self.controller.filterBar)
    {
        _filterBarStartFrame = CGRectMake(0.0, 44.0, 320.0, 0.0);
        CGRect filterBarEndFrame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 320.0, 44.0);
        _tableViewStartFrame = self.controller.tableView.frame;
        CGRect tableViewEndFrame = CGRectMake(self.controller.tableView.frame.origin.x, self.controller.tableView.frame.origin.y + 44.0, self.controller.tableView.frame.size.width, self.controller.tableView.frame.size.height - 44.0);

        self.controller.filterBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:_filterBarStartFrame];
        self.controller.filterBar.delegate = self;
        [self.controller.tableView.superview addSubview:self.controller.filterBar];

        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{self.controller.tableView.frame = tableViewEndFrame;}];
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{self.controller.filterBar.frame = filterBarEndFrame;}];

        tgr = [[FFTapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(filterBarTap:)];
        [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] addGestureRecognizer:tgr];
        [self.controller.filterBar becomeFirstResponder];
    }
}
```

Once the search bar is displayed, I capture and hit test all single taps. If the tap is outside the search bar, I dismiss the search bar:

```
- (void) filterBarTap:(FFTapGestureRecognizer*) sender
{
    if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)
    {
        if (![self.controller.filterBar hitTest:[sender locationInView:self.controller.filterBar] withEvent:nil])
        {
            //if tap is outside filter bar, close the filter bar
            [self searchBarCancelButtonClicked:self.controller.filterBar];
        }
        else
        {
            //pass the tap up the responder chain
            //THIS DOESN'T WORK!
            [self.controller.filterBar touchesEnded:sender.touches withEvent:sender.event];
        }
    }
}
```

However, if the tap is inside the search bar, I want the search bar to process the tap normally. The only way I could see to do this was to send a touchesEnded to the search bar, passing in the touches and event. I don't have the either, so I subclassed the UITapGestureRecognizer to capture both when it receives a touchesEnded:

```
- (void) touchesEnded:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    self.touches = touches;
    self.event = event;

    [super touchesEnded:touches withEvent:event];
}
```

I reimplemented the remaining 3 touches… methods similarly, and I also reimplemented reset to call its superclass.

Alas, all this trickery works except for passing to the search bar the taps that happen inside its frame. Tapping the Cancel button does nothing. Tapping the Clear button does nothing.

Can anyone tell me how I can do this?

Thanks

Comment: I found the answer. I have to pass the touches and event directly to the UIView returned by hitTest:. Here's the corrected filterBarTap: method:

Comment: I found the answer. It works if I pass the touches and event directly to the UIView returned by hitTest:. In filterBarTap: add this before the inner if(): `UIView* target = [self.controller.filterBar hitTest:[sender locationInView:self.controller.filterBar] withEvent:nil];` and the else becomes this: `[target touchesEnded:sender.touches withEvent:sender.event];`